# Why 12 bit ADC output of NUCLEO64-STM32L073RZ fluctuate over 20 steps?

Tags: embedded, stm32, adc, nucleo, stm

I am using the NUCLEO64 Board STM32L073RZ with current sensor IC ACS725. I am using the following ADC and Timer configuration for STM.

[image]
[image]

ADC were configured for auto triger using timer2. Clock frequency was 16Mhz and hence the Timer2 frequency.

NUCLEO board is powered from the USB port of laptop and the ACS725 is powered from the 3.3V output of NUCLEO board. ADC pin is connected to the output of ACS725 output pin and that should produce an output of 1.65V( Half of Vcc).

But when I displayed the ADC output, it was fluctuating more than 20steps. ADC Output is given below.

[image]

My code for reading the ADC value is given below

```
void HAL_ADC_ConvCpltCallback(ADC_HandleTypeDef* hadc)
{
    endOfConversion = 1;
}
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_USART2_UART_Init();
  MX_ADC_Init();
  MX_TIM2_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */

  HAL_ADCEx_Calibration_Start(&hadc, ADC_SINGLE_ENDED);
  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */

  while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
      HAL_TIM_Base_Start(&htim2);
      HAL_ADC_Start_IT(&hadc);
         do
         {
             if(endOfConversion==1)
             {
                 endOfConversion=0;
                 adc_val = HAL_ADC_GetValue(&hadc);
                 volt = (float) (adc_val*3.33)/4095;
                 txcount++;
                 char str[70]={};
                 sprintf(str,"adc = %d, Ic out = %.03f\n\r", adc_val, volt);
                 HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2,(uint8_t *)str, strlen(str), 50);
                 HAL_Delay(500);
             }
         }while(txcount>0);
      HAL_ADC_Stop_IT(&hadc);
      HAL_TIM_Base_Stop(&htim2);

      char *str1 = "NEW SET \n\r";
      HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2,(uint8_t *)str1, strlen(str1), 50);

  }

  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}
```

What causing this fluctuation? I have checked the ADC ref and Vcc of the STM and it is stable.

My connection setup is shown below.

[image]

This is how the ACS725 board look like.

[image]

EDIT : The Ic has inbuilt active filter and I used 1uF capacitor on the filter pin which makes cutoff frequency as 88Hz. Now the large fluctuations are removed. But still, there is a fluctuation about 3 to 7 ADC steps. How to remove all this fluctuations? I cant use averaging because I need to measure AC current

[image]

Comment: 3.3V/4096*20 = 0.016V peak-to-peak, 8mV from the set voltage to either direction, which in my books still falls into the definition of "stable". Sounds like normal noise, especially given we don't know the exact hardware setup (How are the parts connected? Wires? PCB traces? How exactly PCB traces go? Analog ground? Ground currents? etc.). Can you verify with the scope that the signal that goes into the MCU has less peak-to-peak noise than that?

Comment: Increasing your sampling time from 1.5 clocks to more clocks should give you a more stable and accurate result. You might have to reduce your sampling frequency (i.e. the period of TIM2) depending on how high you go.

Comment: I have tried by increasing the sampling time. but it is not working.

Comment: Do you have a decoupling capacitor on the supply pins of your current sensor? These sensors work based on the magnetic field created by the current you want to measure. Like Ilya suggested, the layout of your PCB is very important, otherwise you might measure some external disturbances.

Comment: Yeah I have 0.1uF on Vcc to gnd,

Comment: Is it require any capacitor on output pin?, because datasheet shows one capacitor on output pin but the value is not mentioned.

Comment: The capacitor shown in the data sheet is to illustrate the capacitance of the load attached to the output pin. It is good practice to filter the output signal, e.g. using an RC filter with a bandwidth corresponding to your needs.

Comment: This question belongs on https://electronics.stackexchange.com/. SO is a pure programming site, but this is as much a hardware question as a software one. In particular, your Vref circuitry matters a lot. As does the board layout. I see that you have a blue, a red and a brown antenna to capture radiated emissions, for example... Analog designs need _tight_ layouts. Don't expect great EMC performance desktop lab junk with some eval board...

Comment: Btw that plastic box doesn't look ESD proof. You need to study ESD before doing anything else.

Comment: It is not clear from your description what current is being measured, why would you not expect fluctuations?  Apart from that it is odd and a poor use of resources to auto-trigger the ADC at 16MHz to then only read a single sample at 500ms intervals.  The high constant sample rate might make sense if you were performing signal processing (using DMA).  Signal processing (a low pass filter for example, or even a simple  moving average) would remove the fluctuations.  Asking about that would make this on-topic.

Comment: I am trying to measure 10mA input current and that would produce 0.00264V as per the sensitivity. With this much fluctuations, I can't measure the current without error.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [datasheet](https://www.allegromicro.com/-/media/files/datasheets/acs725-datasheet.pdf) under "Common Electrical Characteristics", the noise level is typically 27 mA (rms).

[image: Datasheet p.6]

Assuming you have the current sensor for the range +/-5A, this translates to an output of 27mA * 264mV/1000mA = 7mV (page 7). Peak to peak, this corresponds to 2 * 7 * sqrt(2) = 19.8mV, so approx. 20mV.

On your 12-bit ADC with a 3.3V reference voltage, this translates to 20mV * 3.3V/4096 = 16 counts, so roughly what you observed.

I would suggest filtering the output signal with a filter. I would use an active filter, because the maximum output capacitance load of the sensor is 10nF (page 6). If this is not an option, be sure the capacitor's value does not exceed these 10nF.

###### EDIT:

It seems the OP wants to measure current in the range of 10mA AC. For this application, this is not the right sensor. This current is less than the input noise level. No matter how much we filter, the sensor would not measure such a current precisely. This is in part due to the physical principle of the measurement (hall effect).

To measure such small currents, I would use a shunt resistor and an appropriate amplifier, for instance the [INA169](https://www.ti.com/product/INA169) from Texas Instruments.

Comment: The filtering could equally be done in the digital domain.  That would at least make the subject on topic rather than a question for https://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Clifford, I cant use the averaging since i need to measure the AC current too.

Comment: @emiled please look at the edit, as you said the filtering removed the large fluctuations but still I observed the 3 to 7 ADC steps fluctuations.

Comment: That is non-sequitur.  Why would one preclude the other? It is not rocket science to retain both the filtered and original signal. Besides if the AC signal is not distinct (by both bandwidth and amplitude) from the noise signal, then you are doomed in any case.  However you have commented in the wrong place.  I made that comment against the question.  A moving average is a special (and simple) case of an FIR filter.  A more sophisticated filter might be advised, but use of one does not imply the removal of the wanted signal - that would depend on the length of the filter.